# how to solve android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to get links in a address, and I use `Jsoup` and `RecyclerView`, so I do this:

```
public static List<News> newsList(String url) {
    List<News> newsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect().get();
        Elements newsElements = document.select(".boxMiddle .grpLinks a");
        int i = 1;
        for (Element newsElement : newsElements) {
            News news = new News();
            news.setId(i);
            news.setTitle(newsElement.text());
            news.setDate(newsElement.attr("title"));
            news.setUrl(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
            newsArrayList.add(news);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newsArrayList;

}
```

However, I get this error: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`!

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use AsyncTask . You cannot make a network call on UIThread.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

use an `AsyncTask` for your I/O. You can't perform networking on the main thread.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

  public void doInBackground(Void... params){
    //I/O here
  }
}.execute();
```